# The reference could not be fetched for (Mongodb/Morphia)

Tags: java, morphia

Since a month ago i am facing a trouble with my Java project which is that when i start the application i get this:

```
Error on start
    https://pastebin.com/raw/sKszKp4K
```

```
And i also get this:
    https://pastebin.com/raw/4m2KzBHv
```

This happens for some users, not to all users, and it happens to for some "factions" that have the users inside, i know that this error has been published on here but i cannot find the solution for this, i am having this error since a lot of time ago and i don't know what to do now :(

```
When i stop the application it throws this error
    https://pastebin.com/hX1R3nza
```

```
My FactionUser.java class:
    https://pastebin.com/6Z68pULe
```

```
My PlayerFaction.java class:
    https://pastebin.com/U7Zj0kGC
```

I'm sorry for not pasting the code here but it doesn't allow me to put more than 30000 chars
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what's going wrong here but I can offer some ideas and see if they lead you anywhere.  For the missing reference errors one of at least 2 two things are likely:

1. The referenced document/entity has been deleted since that reference was saved.  MongoDB does not enforce referential integrity so this happens a fair bit in practice, I think.
2. The referenced ID value does not actually exist in the database because it was never actually saved.  Morphia requires that referenced entities have an ID before the referencing entity is saved.  This is because Morphia needs that ID value to write to the document for the referencing being saved.  Typically, this ID value is generated when the referent is saved.  However, in some cases (e.g., the ID type is not `ObjectId`) that ID is manually set on the referent.  In this case, it's possible to then save the referencing entity because the referent has an ID value in the object even though that referent was never actually saved.  In this case, you'd have a reference to nothing essentially and you'd end up with that error.

If the entity has, in fact, simply been deleted after the reference was saved and that's ok, you can actually tell Morphia to ignore the missing references on the `@Reference` [annotation](https://morphia.dev/1.5.8/javadoc/dev/morphia/annotations/Reference.html#ignoreMissing()) itself.

As for the stack overflow, it seems like you have a loop in your embedded fields and so you might want to make sure you're properly setting up your model.  Morphia does not support cycles like that and so the burden is on the developer to ensure they don't happen.